# Oauth 2 + Spring Security - Getting 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have created a simple web application client using Spring framework. I am using OAuth2RestTemplate to call a third party REST service which requires TLS/SSL connection. I have configured Tomcat to use HTTPS port and specifed the keystore file I created. I have also registered my client app running on Tomcat localhost with the 3rd party resource provider. I have client id, secret and other details that I have specified in my security config XML file. I selected "Authorization Code Grant Type" while registering my web client.

When I make the request I am redirected to the form login for my web client. After authenticating there I am redirected to the 3rd party resource providers site to authenticate the user. When I enter the user name and password I see the page where I need to authorize or deny the request. After this I am getting 403 forbidden error. When I check the 3rd party REST service providers site I can see that a token was generated for my POST request. Logs also indicate the same with Http code 200 Ok. But i believe i am getting 403 Forbidden error when using the token for accessing resources using the Get call of my request.

I have spent quite some time debugging and researching on this issue but no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are some of the code snippets I have.

`security-config.xml`:

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>          
                <user name="mm" password="mm" authorities="ROLE_MAIL_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <http pattern="/**">

        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="https"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll()"  requires-channel="https"/>       
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll()"  requires-channel="https"/>        

        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="https"/>
    <!--    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MAIL_USER')" requires-channel="https"/> -->

        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=1"
                    login-processing-url="/login"/>

        <logout logout-success-url="/build-newsletter.html"/>

        <csrf/>

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443" />
    </port-mappings>

        <custom-filter ref="leg1Filter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>

    </http>

    <oauth2:resource id="tResource" client-id="myclientid"
                                      user-authorization-uri="https://thirdpartyhost/sss/authorize"
                                      access-token-uri="https://thirdpartyhost/oauth2/sss/token"
                                      client-secret="somesecret"
                                      type="authorization_code"
                                      scope="read,write"/>

    <oauth2:rest-template id="tOAuthTemplate" resource="tResource"/>

    <oauth2:client id="leg1Filter"/>

</beans:beans>
```

My Controller:

```java
@Controller
public class TAppController 
{   
    String endPoint = rest api endpoint;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate tOAuthTemplate;

        @RequestMapping("/tEventDetails.html")
        public ModelAndView getEventDetails() {
        List<TEventData> tEventData = (List<TEventData>) tOAuthTemplate.getForObject(endPoint + "tEvents", TEvent.class).getData();

    return new ModelAndView("/tDetailsPage.jsp", "tDetails", tEventData);
    }
    }
```

Redirecting to:

Here are some snippets from the log:

```
13:10:34,957 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:449 - Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.DefaultAccessTokenRequest#1'
13:10:34,960 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:477 - Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.DefaultAccessTokenRequest#1'
13:10:34,968 DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider:159 - Retrieving token from *****thirdpartyhost/oauth2/ss/token
13:10:34,982 DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate:78 - Created POST request for "https://thirdpartyhost/ss/super/token"
13:10:34,983 DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider:221 - Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[cjtjlstkw7uzt7rvim0xq3ogl], redirect_uri=[****localhost:8443/mm/tDetails.html]}
***13:10:35,383 DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate:569 - POST request for "***thirdpartyhost/ss/oauth2/token" resulted in 200 (OK)
13:10:35,403 DEBUG*** org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor:92 - Reading [interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4997b84c]
13:10:35,600 DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate:78 - Created GET request for "*****thirdpartyhost/v7/ss/me/tEvents?limit=5"
13:10:35,628 DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate:669 - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
13:10:35,797  WARN ***org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate:581 - GET request for "****thirdpartyhost/v7/ss/tEvents" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler***
13:10:35,804 DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor:92 - Reading [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@161bd9ce]
13:10:35,806 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [com.pvp.webcontrollers.TCERefAppController@4c233b11]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
13:10:35,807 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [com.pvp.webcontrollers.TCERefAppController@4c233b11]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
13:10:35,807 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [com.pvp.webcontrollers.TRefAppController@4c233b11]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
13:10:35,807 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:984 - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:588)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:546)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
```

From the logs i can see the POST request for getting a Token in exchange of the authorization code is successful. But i get 403 forbidden error when making GET request to access the resources/data from the resource server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. The client i registered with the service provider did not have correct category/group defined. All of their web services are defined under a specific group by product area.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this. I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: It was more related to using the right settings when registering the client with the rest service provider. Also make sure the security settings like domain and security groups on the web service are correct for a client to invoke it.